# How to import date-fns JS library to Rails project using yarn

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date-fns

I try to import `date-fns` lib using `yarn` to Rails project, but it didn't work.

I use `yarn` to install `date-fns`:

`yarn add date-fns`

After install them I try to import this lib to `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file, but it didn't work:

```js
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//

import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import format from "date-fns/format";
```

I got an error:

```sh
> format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
> VM498:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: format is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

If I try import it using `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```js
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require date-fns/format

console.log("date-fns", format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

It seems the library is connected, so I can call the method `format`, but I got another error:

```sh
> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
# refers to this line 
>  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
>   value: true
>  });
> exports.default = format;

# and 

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
# refers to this line 
> function format(dirtyDate, dirtyFormatStr, dirtyOptions) {
>  (0, _index10.default)(2, arguments);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you trying to call the ‘format’ function? The context is important because webpack will not export JS to the global scope by default.

Answer (score 1):

The way to import a library in Webpack and Rails is to install it via yarn, as you did, and then require it in the application pack.

```
# console
$ yarn add date-fns

# app/javascript/packs/application.js
require("date-fns")
```